# Retrieving read/write statistics from DataFrameReader/DataFrameWriter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking for logging capabilities in `PySparks` [DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) and [DataFrameWriter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html). When dataframes are read or written, the number of `files`, `partitions`, `records/rows`, `rawbytes` etc. involved in the operation should be tracked and returned to be usable afterwards.

I have checked official `Apache Spark` documentation and searched with Google, but seems to be no such capability implemented in `PySpark` right now. These are ideas I came up with:

- Checking same directories (used at read/write) with `dbutils` in `Databricks`, cloud provider libraries (`boto3` for AWS S3 or `azure-storage-blob` for Azure) or `Python` builtin `os` package
- Interact with `SparkContext` and use something like [StatusTracker](https://www.javatpoint.com/pyspark-statustracker) to monitor job/stage progress and return job information via `jobId` (-> not checked)
- Run `Spark` in some kind of debug/dryrun mode and extract infos from loggers (-> not checked)

But I am more looking for any easy-to-use implementation like with a fictional `option("statistics", "true")` setting:

```py
df, read_statistics = spark.read.option("statistics", "true").csv("inputfile.csv")

write_statistics = df.write.option("statistics", "true").csv("outputfile.csv")
```

Thanks in advance for any insights on alternative implementations or future release plans of the community!

**SOLUTION (partial):**

An easy-to-use solution (for number of `bytes` and `records`) based on collecting and aggregating `Spark` events is via `ContextSparkListener` from [pyspark-spy](https://github.com/sashgorokhov/pyspark-spy) package:

```py
from pyspark_spy import ContextSparkListener, register_listener

listener = ContextSparkListener()
register_listener(spark_context, listener)

with listener as events:
    df = spark.read.csv("inputfile.csv")
    spark.write.csv("outputfile.csv")

print("Read statistics: ", listener.stage_input_metrics_aggregate())
print("Write statistics: ", listener.stage_output_metrics_aggregate())

>>> Read statistics:  InputMetrics(bytesRead=140129708, recordsRead=271502)
>>> Write statistics:  OutputMetrics(bytesWritten=136828555, recordsWritten=265106)
```

Comment: Spark provides a callback `SparkListenerInterface` and default no-op implementation.

Comment: @mazaneicha Thanks for hinting to `SparkListenerInterface`. This is partly resolving the question due to only `bytes` and `records` are loggable when checking [OutputMetrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/status/api/v1/OutputMetrics.html). So am I right, that logging number of `partitions` or `files` is not implemented to `SparkListener` itselt?

Comment: Not entirely. You can find all kind of info by interrogating `RDDInfo`, `StageInfo`, etc. data objects.

Comment: @mazaneicha Looks promising, thanks for pointing out. When checking [RDDInfo](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/storage/RDDInfo.html) the number of `partitions` is easily available. Will check it soonly and post my solution with `PySpark`